# Rotate an SVG in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an SVG that I've created in react native, and I'd simply like to rotate this 360 degrees continuously in the most efficient way possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Just wrap your SVG in a View component and make use of the Animated API. Your code would be something in the lines of this:

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animation = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  render() {

    const rotation = this.animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
    });

    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{transform: [{rotate: rotation}] }}
      >
        <YourSVG />
      </Animated.View>
    );


  componentDidMount() {

    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.animation, {toValue: 1, duration: 2000})
    ).start();    
  }
}
```

Comment: What if YourSVG has an internal translation and you only want to rotate that part of the SVG? Something like

```
<Svg width={100} height={100}>
    <Rect width={'100%'} height={'100%'} fill={'blue'}/>
    <Rect width={20} height={20} x={20} y={60} fill={'red'}/>
</Svg>
```

where you want to rotate the red rectangle.

Comment: I'm getting `Invariant Violation: outputRange cannot include 0deg`

Comment: looks like you have to use `concat` from `Animated` e.g. `{ transform: [{ rotate: concat(this.animation, 'deg') }] },` https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/584

Comment: do you know how to flip svg on x-axis

Answer (score 11):

Just use transform. It works perfectly.

```
<YourSvg
    height={20}
    width={20}
    style={{ transform: [{ rotateY: '180deg' }] }}
/>
```

Comment: `style={{transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}]}}` This works for me

Answer (score 2):

Add in `Svg` tag:

`style={{ transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }] }}`